# Rails Minitest: Can I specify fixture relations via `has_many`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, minitest

I'm rather confused by https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Label+references+for+associations+-28belongs_to-2C+has_one-2C+has_many-29, specifically their example where it appears that the `Pirate` model with a `has_many :monkeys` relationship is defining a fixture association on the `has_many` side.

That is, the pirate `reginald` has a `monkey: george`

```
### in pirates.yml

reginald:
  name: Reginald the Pirate
  monkey: george

### in monkeys.yml

george:
  name: George the Monkey
  pirate: reginald
```

However, when I try something similar (slightly different), I receive an error.

```
# test/fixtures/books.yml
book_one:
  title: lorem
  chapters: chapter_one, chapter_two

# test/fixtures/chapters.yml
chapter_one
  title: foo

chapter_two
  title: bar

# Error when running fixtures/testing
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "books" has no columns named "chapters"
```

I was further confused by another example, which appears to show a fixture for a model that `has_many :fruits` provide a list of fruits to associate with in the fixture. Yes, the document displays this example under `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, but I thought maybe it would also work for `has_many` relationships as well.

```
### in monkeys.yml

george:
  id: 1
  name: George the Monkey
  fruits: apple, orange, grape

### in fruits.yml

apple:
  name: apple

orange:
  name: orange

grape:
  name: grape
```

So am I out to lunch on this? Its unfortunate because it would be nice to be able to specify fixture associtions on the `has_many` side.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, fixtures can not create associated records before the parent model. I would suggest looking at factory_bot surely can use callbacks to create related records:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :monkey do
    name { "George the Monkey" }

    after(:create) do |monkey, evaluator|
      create_list(:fruit, 5, monkey: monkey)
      monkey.reload
    end
  end
end
```